# Matplotlib Histogram looks incorrect (only one bin)

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, subplot

I am trying to create several subplots, but half of them look weird

[image: picture of histograms]

It seems like the y-axis values are off. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4,ax5) = plt.subplots(1,5, figsize = (16,4))
ax1.hist(df['AVG_TIME_BETWEEN_PURCHASES'], edgecolor = 'white', align = 'mid', bins=20)
ax1.set_xlabel('Abstand zw. Käufen')
ax1.set_ylabel('Count')
ax2.hist(df['DAYS_SINCE_LAST_ORDER'], edgecolor = 'white', align = 'mid', bins=20)
ax2.set_xlabel('vergangene Tage')
ax3.hist(df['CUSTOMER_LIFETIME_VALUE'], edgecolor = 'white')
ax3.set_xlabel('Total Revenue')
ax4.hist(df['AVERAGE_ORDER_VALUE'], edgecolor = 'white', align = 'mid')
ax4.set_xlabel('Avg Revenue')
ax5.hist(df['CATEGORY_REVENUE_PARFUM'], edgecolor = 'white', align = 'mid')
ax5.set_xlabel('Revenue Parfum')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without seeing more of your code and the associated data, but I notice that `ax3`, `ax4`, and `ax5` do not specify a `bins=20` in their method calls.

These also appear to be the graphs that look incorrect.

Have you tried adding that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, there may be a few outliers in the data set. I would check the max values in `CUSTOMER_LIFETIME_VALUE`, `AVERAGE_ORDER_VALUE` and `CATEGORY_REVENUE_PARFUM`.